# JSONSchema - Required property dependent on parent property

Tags: javascript, jsonschema, ajv

I would like to apply an additional "required" property in an array sub schema based on the presence of a property in the root schema. I have my schema set like this:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "required":[
       "isParentDependency",
       "subArray"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "isParentDependency": {
            "$id": "#/properties/isParentDependency",
            "type": "boolean"
        },
        "subArray": {
            "$id": "#/properties/subArray",
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "$id": "#/properties/subArrayItem",
                "required": ["alwaysRequiredProp"],
                "dependencies": {
                    "isParentDependency":{
                        "required":["requiredPropIfIsParentDependency"]
                    }
                },
                "properties": {
                    "alwaysRequiredProp": {
                        "$id": "#/properties/subArray/items/properties/alwaysRequiredProp",
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "requiredPropIfIsParentDependency": {
                        "$id": "#/properties/subArray/items/properties/requiredPropIfIsParentDependency",
                        "type": "boolean"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Passing Cases

```
{
    "isParentDependency": false,
    "subArray": [{
        "alwaysRequiredProp": true
    }]
}
```

```
    "isParentDependency": true,
    "subArray": [{
        "alwaysRequiredProp": true,
        "requiredPropIfIsParentDependency":true
    }]
}
```

#### Failing Cases

```
{
    "isParentDependency": true,
    "subArray": [{
        "alwaysRequiredProp": true
    }]
}
```

Clearly this is not going to work but I have been unable to figure out how to make a pointer to the root schema (or apply an if/else type solution with a $ref)

Any guidance greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can't "see up" the tree, so you have to define what you need at the root level and use subschemas. I'm happy to help, but could you clean up your example first please? Not complete JSON, and does not identify which draft it is using (I'm going to assume draft-7). Additionally, please provide a JSON instance for your pass and fail conditions (this will allow me to give you a quicker answer).

Comment: Thanks very much @Relequestual - I have (hopefully) fleshed out the Q with what you need

Comment: Super. Working...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With JSON Schema, each level of nested `properties` down the tree cannot see up the tree. Therefore you have to define your conditions at the top most level to which it needs to see. In this case, that's the root level.

Take a look at this schema.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "definitions": {
    "subArray": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "required": [
          "alwaysRequiredProp"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "alwaysRequiredProp": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "requiredPropIfIsParentDependency": {
            "type": "boolean"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "isParentDependency",
    "subArray"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "isParentDependency": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "subArray": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/subArray"
    }
  },
  "if": {
    "properties": {
      "isParentDependency": {
        "const": true
      }
    }
  },
  "then": {
    "properties": {
      "subArray": {
        "items": {
          "required": [
            "requiredPropIfIsParentDependency"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`subArray` has been moved to a definition and then referenced, so the conditional application logic can be seen easier.

The definition of `subArray` only determines the properties of the items structure if they are provided, and requires `alwaysRequiredProp`. It does not require `requiredPropIfIsParentDependency`.

The conditional application comes in using the `if` and `then` keywords.

If the `if` schema is true, then the `else` schema is applied.

The value of `if` is a schema. It is applicable to the root level. It requires `isParentDependency` be `true` (it does not require the property itself, because that is ALWAYS required. Requiring the property inside the if statement would NOT mean the property is always required, unless `else` was `false`, but we're not even using `else` here).

When `isParentDependency` is `true`, the `then` schema is applied, which looks down the tree to `subArray`'s items, requiring `requiredPropIfIsParentDependency`.

You can test this working in browser using [jsonschema.dev](https://jsonschema.dev/s/N4IgziBcLAOgdgAkbEASMBjAFgUwLYCGqkKI2ALhQA6QD0dAVmAPbwC0WeRAdCwE4BzOgBN+hAGYV2ABgDsdLgUIBiVABoEyVBQCe1XCTIsARo1yYKGrWRG4JAS3gOKDtmCNwkyMmACuJgCC-OK6njY+ZHoGRqiEIYRhIJrekaguBB5QiF6RaSD8uACOfg6FIkYA2hF52iCEADYA7olgAErFpeUACvws1Kg1kQC6KbV11H0G-K64WaS543WNLbrtnWW4Ir394alLUfqG2agmLCwNuITwg-u1AL5jB6iFJZvbUwCSEp9g3fG4eAUAAiuAM8Ds8EwSQWQ3GOiOsRAZwuVxuIDhkXumMQ2LuuJqeOQjxsLw25SqNXSfwBQNB4Mh0Os+1Q-iCCSSNlGpJAk36uBmDjme3yDhphTpYMBjJhOThCJiJ2R50u11uWKedTZwVCIryqDQhQkSJUonsThcbngYEUAR1iXVPiJuKe6WN2UWEymAtm8zl+Op-wlIKlEMBTI9ONQmHcVmyFH4fkM+OdxJsJO8Ojw6NhLN53sFwsjAfAdo5etq6QomQr8IK5K2lPxlfrbx6Xx+4sBIYZ4c5zZ8wxxqadhPTCHuyRADigMB5YqD3fp0r7RgTSddpfZuuy1X2np8cWarQ6ba2OwG8cTyaxXInIHuQA) (preloaded with this schema and your fail instance).

Comment: You EAT JSONSchema!! Thats a great explanation - adding as a definition is the bit I had failed to grasp. Thanks very much!

Comment: You're welcome Mike. I am one of the spec writers and admins so I know it pretty well. Feel free to join our slack via the website discussion link.

Comment: Well then thanks for all your hard work! I am using it for the validation of state in React across many interrelated components and is proving to be a very tidy solution

Comment: Welcome! We are unfunded, so if you want to support us, see the link in my profile. We hope to have an OpenCollective soon too.

Comment: Done and cheap at twice the price!

Comment: Very kind! Thanks. The door is always open in the Slack. We pick up all SO questions tagged with `jsonschema`!