# Dependency on the existence of a nested value

Tags: jsonschema, jsonforms

I can get `dependencies` to work with non-nested values (top-level in the schema), but I would like for a dependency to be dependent on a property which is nested within an `object` definition.

```js
const schema = {
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    start: {
      type: "object",
      properties: {
        time: {
          type: "string"
        }
      }
    }
  },

  dependencies: {
    start: {
      properties: {
        end: {
          type: "object",
          properties: {
            time: {
              type: "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Essentially, I want a way for the dependency to depend *not* on the `start` property, but on the `start.time` property.

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57627367/dependencies-between-fields-in-parallel-sub-schemas) issue and the answer states that the schema cannot look "up" the tree, though I am not fully certain what "up" and "down" mean in this context.

The way I see it, if the dependency can depend on `start`, and `time` is a property within `start`, then `time` is "down" the tree, not "up" (?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dependencies` keyword exists to simplify the schema for a specific use case. It sacrifices some flexibility and expressiveness for more simple syntax. Although your use case is very similar, it falls outside of what `dependencies` can do. The good news is that there's a way to do it.

This,

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "some-propery-name": { ... some-schema ... }
  }
}
```

Is equivalent to,

```json
{
  "if": { "required": ["some-property-name"] },
  "then": { ... some-schema ... }
}
```

You can extrapolate from there to describe your use case.

```json
{
  "if": {
    "properties": {
      "start": { "required": ["time"] }
    },
    "required": ["start"]
  },
  "then": { ... some-schema ... }
}
```