# JSON Schema - Child type dependant on parent element name (with Json.Net)

Tags: json.net, jsonschema

Having following JSON schema:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "SomeForms": {
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "Forms": {
          "type": "object",
          "additionalProperties": false,
          "patternProperties": {
            "^(TestTestForm1|TestForm2)$": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "Options": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "additionalProperties": false,
                  "patternProperties": {
                    "^(ExampleDropdown|ExampleCheckboxes)$": {
                      "type": "object",
                      "properties": {
                        "DefaultValue": {
                          "type": "string"
}}}}}}}}}}}}}
```

And following test JSON:

```
{
  "SomeForms": {
    "Forms": {
      "TestTestForm1": {
        "Options": {
          "ExampleDropdown": {
            "DefaultValue": "Dropdown"
}}}}}}
```

How I can make the `DefaultValue` have different `type`, depending on the parent `"^(TestTestForm1|TestForm2)$"`?
Example:
- if the parent is `TestTestForm1`, I want `DefaultValue` to be `number`
- if the parent is `TestTestForm1`, I want `DefaultValue` to be `string`

I am using `Json.NET` library to generate schemas, so the `C#` example would be best, but having JSON schema example would also be a clue for me.

Thanks in advance.

I tried:

```
"Forms": {
    "allOf": [
    { 
            "if": { "patternProperties": { "const": "TestTestForm1" } }, 
            "then": { "patternProperties" : { "TestTestForm1": { "properties": { "Options": { "patternProperties": { "properties": { "DefaultValue": { "type": "number" } } } } } } } } }
],
```

But I does not work.
Main thing I don't know, is how to make "if" check on the parent name, not the value (above I am using "const", which I guess is correct only for checking the "value" of property, not it's name).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to set the type of a schema object based on the value of another property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53881623/how-to-set-the-type-of-a-schema-object-based-on-the-value-of-another-property) I'm not sure but it looks like a question I've had a few years back. Check out the answer I've got, it worked perfectly in my case.

Comment: Hi. So the main issue I have is that I want to do "if" on the name of property, not it's value. I am not sure, how the "if" condition should look like in that case.

Comment: I edited description and added question about "if" structure.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not an expert on JsonSchema. In fact, I haven't used it in over two years. The user that answered my question is an expert on this subject, I'll bet he can help you. Unfortunately, Stackoverflow doesn't really give you the ability to ping a specific user.... Hopefully, you'll get your answer.

Comment: i think it was covered in this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57141416/jsonschema-required-property-dependent-on-parent-property

Comment: Already saw that one. Againg, it is checking the "property value", while I need to check the property name. Not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't "look up" the schema tree in JSON Schema. So you need to put the condition the level of the Forms object as you did. But this results in a quite verbose solution like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "description": "JSON schema generated with JSONBuddy https://www.json-buddy.com",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "SomeForms": {
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "Forms": {
          "type": "object",
          "additionalProperties": false,
          "patternProperties": {
            "^(TestTestForm1|TestForm2)$": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "foo": { },
                "bar": { }
              }
            }
          },
          "allOf": [
            {
              "if": {
                "properties": { "TestTestForm1": true }
              },
              "then": {
                "properties": {
                  "TestTestForm1": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                      "Options": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "patternProperties": {
                          "^(ExampleDropdown|ExampleCheckboxes)$": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                              "DefaultValue": {
                                "type": "string"
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "if": {
                "properties": { "TestForm2": true }
              },
              "then": {
                "properties": {
                  "TestForm2": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                      "Options": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "patternProperties": {
                          "^(ExampleDropdown|ExampleCheckboxes)$": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                              "DefaultValue": {
                                "type": "number"
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I added empty definitions for "foo" and "bar" keys at the place where you could add parts of the schema which are in common.

I can't think of any shorter version to solve this.